# Sorting by several array columns with usort

Tags: php, arrays, array-column

I am aware of the fact that I can usort an array by one column using something like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return $b['column'] - $a['column'];
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

This simulates the `ORDER BY column DESC`.

What if I want to simulate the `ORDER BY column1 DESC, column2 ASC` or `ORDER BY column1, column2 DESC` or also by more columns? Is it possible with PHP or it's pretty much a work that just SQL can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you mean [array-multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

> array_multisort — Sort multiple or multi-dimensional arrays

Simple example:

```
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 1);
$data[] = array('volume' => 85, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 98, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 7);

array_multisort(array_column($data, 'volume'), SORT_DESC, array_column($data, 'edition'), SORT_ASC, $data);
```

This will make `$data` sort first by volume field in DESC and then by edition field in ASC.

Comment: While it will sort by multiple columns it will not sort with usort. So if you have one column where you not just need a compare function you will have to use usort. And the question was "...with usort" :)

Comment: Literally you right and you solution will work fine also. But I think this is what the OP actually wanted even if he didn't know it...

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. Sorting by multiple columns means that you just use another sort criterium if the first sort criterium is equal:

```php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
  if ($a['col1'] !== $b['col1']) {
    return $b['col1'] - $a['col1'];
  }
  return $a['col2'] - $b['col2'];
}

usort($array, 'cmp');
```

this is the same like `ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 ASC`

While it seems some bit more code than the multisort it is much more flexible. Depends if you want to calculate something inside. For example: sort by the length of a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using foreach loop, $data sorting.

```
<?php
   $data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 1);
$data[] = array('volume' => 85, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 98, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 7);

// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $volume[$key]  = $row['volume'];
    $edition[$key] = $row['edition'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC, $edition, SORT_ASC, $data);
var_dump($data);
```

Working [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/57V2F)